# Using toggle to hide and unhide page sections

Tags: jquery, html

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/36HP7/2/ fiddle and i am trying to hide a blog post and only show the blog heading and teaser(excerpt).To do that,i am using toggle this way

```
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','none');

$('.the_post_title').toggle(
  function(){
$('.the_post_teaser').css('display','none');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','');
  },
  function(){
$('.the_post_teaser').css('display','');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','none');
  }
);
```

I got it to work using this snippet but somewhere down this road i am forced to have a dedicated css class.

```
$('.the_post_title').on('click',function(){
$('.the_post_teaser').css('display','none');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','');
});
```

How can i solve this using `toggle()`

Comment: you can use the `hide()` and `show()` functions to change the display. Also when you do it using css you change the display to `block` to show the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with the help of an if `if` http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/wjfFb/1/

```
$('.the_post_title').on('click', function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('data-toggled') || $(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'off'){

           $(this).attr('data-toggled','on');
           $('.the_post_teaser').css('display','none');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('data-toggled') == 'on'){
           $(this).attr('data-toggled','off');
           $('.the_post_teaser').css('display','');
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sure it does.Its great.I have given it thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function or two and just call that if you like

```
function showpost(){
   $('.the_post_teaser').hide();
   $('.entire_blog_post').show();
}

function hidepost(){
    $('.the_post_teaser').show();
    $('.entire_blog_post').hide();
}
```

Then for the clicker

```
$('.the_post_title').click(function(){
    if($('.the_post_teaser').css('display') == 'block'){
        showpost();
    } else {
        hidepost();
    }
});
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/36HP7/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('.entire_blog_post').css('display','none');

$('.the_post_title').click( function() {
  $('.the_post_teaser').toggle();
  $('.entire_blog_post').toggle();
});
```

And you might as well just add style="display: none;" to the div with the class 'entire_blog_post' instead of using js to add that property.

Comment: I have tried that already and that just makes it move up and down forever.

Comment: Well, when you click the title it toggles (switches between showing excerpt and article). What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: That it solves but it toggles uncontrollably and just never stops.

Comment: You mean it just keeps on showing and hiding for you? Are you using the code exactly as I wrote it? This way, it's only toggling when you click.

Comment: Well,your answer does the job but in my case i am doing a couple of other things inside toggle.